# RxJava: create a self-dependent stream

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Say, I want to make an `Observable` in RxJava, which has a feedback coupling like on the image below.

[image: Self-dependent stream]

I've managed to achieve that with the use of subjects, like this:

```
// Observable<Integer> source = Observable.range(0, 6);

public Observable<Integer> getFeedbackSum(Observable<Integer> source) {
    UnicastSubject<Integer> feedback = UnicastSubject.create();
    Observable<Integer> feedbackSum = Observable.zip(source, feedback.startWith(0), Pair::create)
        .map(pair -> pair.first + pair.second);

    feedbackSum.subscribe(feedback);
    return feedbackSum;
}
```

It looks rather ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: There is an operator for it: [`scan`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#scan(R,%20io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction)).

Comment: Yeah, totally overlooked it. Thanks, @akarnokd!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an operator for this: [`scan`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#scan(R,%20io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction)):

> `public final <R> Observable<R> scan(R initialValue, BiFunction<R,? super T,R> accumulator)`

```
Observable.range(0, 6)
    .scan(0, (a, b) -> a + b)
    .test()
    .assertResut(0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21);
```

In case your accumulator type is not immutable, you can use [`scanWith`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#scanWith(java.util.concurrent.Callable,%20io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction)):

> `public final <R> Observable<R> scanWith(Callable<R> seedSupplier, BiFunction<R,? super T,R> accumulator)`

Comment: `scanWith` example: `static int initial = 1; .... Observable.range(1,2).scanWith(()->initial++, (a,b)->a+b).repeat(2).subscribe(out::println); `. Result: 1,2,4,2,3,5